# In notepad ++ how can I remove a property from all items in a json list

Tags: notepad++

I have a large json list that has this structure

```
  {
    "name": "my name",
    "description": "my description",
    "image": "image.png",       
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "my name",
    "description": "my description",
    "image": "image.png",       
    "id": 2
  }
...
```

My list is 100 items long. Is there a way to remove the "id" property (and value) from all the objects in the list using notepad++?

Comment: You could write a simple js logic to do it in the console of a browser, but how to do it with notepad++, I don't know if its even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `,\s+"id":.+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
,           # a comma
\s+         # 1 or more spaces, including linebreak
"id":       # literally
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would say just use the find & replace function:
For example:

You want to remove the property image, just use:

```
Find = "image": ".*",

Replace = 

Search Mode = Regular expression
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove the id property, which is a number and has no quotes.

Comment: I tried using "id":[^"]* but it's giving me too much

Comment: Just use "id":.*